# Attempt to get property CheckOutType of SPFile cause 'System.NullReferenceException' exception

Tags: development, splistitem, spfile

I have a strange situation: If the "Require Check Out" and "Create Major Versions" options are switched on for the current Document Library, then when I try to get the CheckOutType property I receive the exception shown below.

> item.File.CheckOutType    'item.File.CheckOutType'
>   threw an exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException'   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.SPCheckOutType
>   {System.NullReferenceException}

Does anyone know the cause of this issue?

UPD: I use SharePoint 2010, RTM. Here is the code, which cause the exception:

> if (item.File.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
>      {
>          //Something else here;
>      }

And here is Exception StackTrace:

> "   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl,
>   ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean
>   bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus,
>   Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs,
>   UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32&
>   pdwNumberOfDirs)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String
>   strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags,
>   Boolean throwException,
>   SPBasePermissions& permMask)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean
>   throwException)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_CheckOutType()\r\n
>   at *My Method here* " string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

When using SPListItem from a SPQuery, to access `.File` properties ensure you have fully loaded the item

```
item = SPList.GetItemById(item.Id)
```

**ORIGINAL (Wrong)**

CheckOutType is an enumeration (value type) so can't be null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28VS.80%29.aspx

My guess is that `item.File` is `null`

Try using:

```
SPFile file = doclib.RootFolder.Files["documentname"]
file.CheckOutType
```

Comment: SPListItem.File and also SPFile.Item often return null in different scenarios. Rather than trying to indirectly retrieve the File or Item object, use the actual getters (if available) or the index enumerators (like in this answer) to get the item. I'll need to do a bit more research to find out why this is, possible deep-deep-deep-dive blog post on this coming up soon.

Comment: @James: Interesting *answer*

Comment: I know, right? :P Decided to write that as a comment because it basically reads "Yeah, djeeg is right, because SharePoint is unpredictable at times, let me fire up ILSpy in a couple of days and I'll let you know why".

Comment: `SPFile file = doclib.RootFolder.Files["documentname"]` - after this code, I recommend you always use `if (file.Exists)` construction. From my experience, this is a very good practice, really!

Comment: @MrBubbles: Suddenly I feel you need to post the erroring code and the SharePoint version you're working with, because that error deserves an API dig.

Comment: @djeeg: File definitely isn't NULL. More then that, i have received this exception few times. 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile' does not contain a definition for 'CheckedOutType' and no extension method 'CheckedOutType' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Strange isn't it?

Comment: @mrbubbles, is this 2007 or 2010?

Comment: @Stuart Pegg: I use SharePoint 2010, RTM (without any hotfixes). Erroring code is: `if (item.File.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None) { //Something else here }`. I can post the StackTrace if you want.

Comment: @MrBubbles: Please do. If you edit it all into your question you'll help later answerers too.

Comment: @mrbubbles, can you post the code where you are creating 'item'

Comment: @djeeg: There is very simple CAML query: `public static SPListItemCollection GetItemsInFolder(string strId, SPList list)  
{  
  SPQuery spq = new SPQuery();  
                spq.Query = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", strId);  
                spq.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";  
  SPListItemCollection spListItemCol = list.GetItems(spq);  
  return spListItemCol;  
}`  And after i simply loop through this SPListItemCollection by foreach.

Comment: my guess is that SPQuery does not return all the properties, try calling: `item = SPList.GetItemById(item.Id)` to fully load the item

Comment: @djeeg: You're right! It works this way. Thanks a lot! Could you please post your answer separate? I'd love to mark it as solution.

Comment: @mrbubbles, i've updated this answer, and kept the original text (as a few comments refer to it)

Comment: What's weird is that the comment MrBubbles made here with the CAML query is pretty much identical to what is called with SPList.GetItemById, except the value type is Integer within the API and not Number.

Comment: @James Love: I've changed "Number" to "Integer" in my CAML query, but I still get 'System.NullReferenceException' exception. Maybe I getting corrupted SPList for some reason or something else affects on query execution, I really don't know :(.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check out using a debugger what returns null. From the statement you posted it could be:

- item is null
- File is null
- Inside the implementation of CheckOutType a nullreference is throw.

Use a debugger to figure this out.

Comment: You dont need the debugger to trace the error; item.File is not null because otherwise the message would be 'item.File' threw an exception..., CheckOutType is not null because it is an enumeration

Comment: @djeeg: SPFile.CheckOutType is a property, which may be doing further work to return the enumerated value; thus the exception could be raised there. *SP*CheckOutType is the enumeration (the type of the property).

Comment: ... ah yes, true

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem that we figured out.

When we call:

```
SPList list = web.GetListFromUrl(...)
foreach(SPItem item in list.Items)
{
  if (item.File.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
  {
   //Something else here;
  }
}
```

in rare cases and for a specific item id (lets say item id = 524) the code will always run into a deadlock. It means the program will hang at the call of

```
  item.File.CheckOutType
```

It will not return, not throw an exception and will never timeout. You can run the code as often as you want, it would always hang on this item id 524.

When we call this via rootfolder (calling the file of the trouble causing item id):

```
SPList List = web.GetListFromUrl(...)
SPFolder Folder = List.RootFolder;
foreach(SPfile File in Folder.Files)
{
  if (File.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
  {
     //Something else here;
  }
}
```

it will work. Same with Item.File.length and File.Length. But: Item.File.Name will work.

Interesting thing: If you identify such a trouble causing item and make a check out and check in from inside the browser, it looks like something is cleaned up and also the loop through this List.Items will work (till another item might cause the problem).

I have heared something about that this is because Files and Items are managed separatly (SPRootFolder and SPList) and that in rare cases the reference of the file in the Item is not loaded correctly or might get lost.

So you have more information on this? Or does anyone else noticed a simlar problem?